# How to restrict method access one child class using inheritance in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code

```
using System;


public class parent
{
    public virtual void m1(){

    }
}
public class child1:parent{

    public sealed override void m1(){

    }
}

public class child2:parent{

    public override void m1(){    //How to stop parent method here

    }

}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

In the above code i have three classes. In parent class contains a virtual method that can be inherit in to child1 class only . How to restrict to inherit parent method in child2 class in c#.net.

Comment: I don't get any error copy pasting the same code, and it compiles just fine.

Comment: I am also not getting error , but i want to restrict that parent method in child2 class

Comment: If you're wanting to make a class be used for only `child1`, why not just make it a private inner class? Unless there's more code in the class that other classes can inherit.

Comment: oops sorry, I thought you said you were getting a compiler error. // raise error comment was not clear.

Comment: Is this an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: It simply does not make sense to have a method in a base class that is intended for only 1 subclass. Put the method in the subclass. That's what subclasses are for, adding unique stuff to a common base.

Comment: @durgasivakishoremopuru try to split the `parent` class into more than one class and in that have a class that can be inherit by any other class , so that  `child2` would inherit from it and then extend your partial `parent` class add rest of the methods ,let `child1` inherit from that extended class . by this way you can achieve your task

Answer (score 2):

If I understand from your question than you want to restrict Parent Class only need to be inherited by Only One Class and no other class need to be inherited from that class.

Simple Answer is No. This is not possible.

Simple rule is if you have make class public and method virtual then it can be inherited by n number of class.

Comment: This is why interfaces are important.